# NIntegrate returns TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] when called in another function

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, precision-and-accuracy

I try to perform some numerical integration with high precision on version

```
In[1]:= $Version

Out[1]= "13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"
```

Here is an example of two integrations:

```
test[1] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/\[Pi] 64 Re[
     1/Gamma[31083/12433 + I x] Gamma[-(31083/12433) - I x] Gamma[
       18649/12433 - I x] Gamma[-(6216/12433) + I x] Gamma[
       6217/12433 + I x] Gamma[
       18650/12433 + I x] (-3 HarmonicNumber[6216/12433 - I x] + 
        3 HarmonicNumber[-(18649/12433) + I x] + 
        2 HarmonicNumber[-(6216/12433) + I x] + 
        HarmonicNumber[6217/12433 + I x] - 
        HarmonicNumber[
         18650/12433 + I x])], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity], 
   MaxPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
   Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 100];
test[2] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/\[Pi] 64 Re[
     1/Gamma[45643/18257 + I x] Gamma[-(45643/18257) - I x] Gamma[
       27385/18257 - I x] Gamma[-(9128/18257) + I x] Gamma[
       9129/18257 + I x] Gamma[
       27386/18257 + I x] (9 HarmonicNumber[9128/18257 - I x]^2 + 
        9 HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I x]^2 + 
        4 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x] + 
        4 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x]^2 + 
        2 HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I x] + 
        4 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x] HarmonicNumber[
          9129/18257 + I x] + HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I x]^2 + 
        6 HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I x] (1 + 
           2 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x] + 
           HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I x] - 
           HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I x]) - 
        6 HarmonicNumber[
          9128/18257 - I x] (1 + 
           3 HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I x] + 
           2 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x] + 
           HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I x] - 
           HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I x]) - 
        2 HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I x] - 
        4 HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I x] HarmonicNumber[
          27386/18257 + I x] - 
        2 HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I x] HarmonicNumber[
          27386/18257 + I x] + HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I x]^2 + 
        9 PolyGamma[1, 27385/18257 - I x] + 
        9 PolyGamma[1, -(9128/18257) + I x] + 
        4 PolyGamma[1, 9129/18257 + I x] + 
        PolyGamma[1, 27386/18257 + I x] - 
        PolyGamma[1, 
         45643/18257 + I x])], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity], 
   MaxPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
   Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 100];
```

It works perfectly by calling the definitions one by one:

```
In[4]:= test[1]

Out[4]= 74.73559493169237253652241059827509951514903612142921777485353238824945584501166308957332833248688493

In[5]:= test[2]

Out[5]= 1402.471472250675436406555484025573957230081133612140431340914964614744180265554621788401770210682144
```

However, calling them in a table like:

```
In[6]:= Table[test[j], {j, 1, 2}]

Out[6]= {74.73559493169237253652241059827509951514903612142921777485353238824945584501166308957332833248688493, TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]}
```

the second integrals returns TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"].

Evaluating with higher recursion limit like

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, $IterationLimit = Infinity}, 
 Table[test[j], {j, 1, 2}]]
```

just makes Mathematica crash.

How can I compute these integrals one by one in an automatized way? (I have thousands of them).

Addendum: It seems that using For, ParallelizeTable, or Hold+ReleaseHold does not solve the issue.

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Please submit report to support@wolfram.com

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Any idea to get around the problem?

Comment: Definitely, this is a bug introduced some day after Mathematica 8.0.4 which works well with this problem.

Comment: I'll report the underlying bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

`Block[{}, test[2]]` and `Module[{}, test[2]]` have the same problem. (`With` works, but I'd think it would be different.)

A workaround is to raise `WorkingPrecision` (it should be higher than `PrecisionGoal` anyway):

```
test[2] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/\[Pi]  64  Re[
     1/Gamma[45643/18257 + I  x]  Gamma[-(45643/18257) - I  x]  Gamma[
       27385/18257 - I  x]  Gamma[-(9128/18257) + I  x]  Gamma[
       9129/18257 + I  x]  Gamma[
       27386/18257 + I  x]  (9  HarmonicNumber[9128/18257 - I  x]^2 + 
        9  HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I  x]^2 + 
        4  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x] + 
        4  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x]^2 + 
        2  HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I  x] + 
        4  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x]  HarmonicNumber[
          9129/18257 + I  x] + HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I  x]^2 + 
        6  HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I  x]  (1 + 
           2  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x] + 
           HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I  x] - 
           HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I  x]) - 
        6  HarmonicNumber[
          9128/18257 - I  x]  (1 + 
           3  HarmonicNumber[-(27385/18257) + I  x] + 
           2  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x] + 
           HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I  x] - 
           HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I  x]) - 
        2  HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I  x] - 
        4  HarmonicNumber[-(9128/18257) + I  x]  HarmonicNumber[
          27386/18257 + I  x] - 
        2  HarmonicNumber[9129/18257 + I  x]  HarmonicNumber[
          27386/18257 + I  x] + 
        HarmonicNumber[27386/18257 + I  x]^2 + 
        9  PolyGamma[1, 27385/18257 - I  x] + 
        9  PolyGamma[1, -(9128/18257) + I  x] + 
        4  PolyGamma[1, 9129/18257 + I  x] + 
        PolyGamma[1, 27386/18257 + I  x] - 
        PolyGamma[1, 
         45643/18257 + I  x])], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity], 
   MaxPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
   Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 250];
```

Comment: **test /@ Range[2]** I am afraid this does not work on my version of Mathematica (V14). I did actually try this among other things. Screen shot:  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eddK9.png)  (from clean kernel)

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for checking. It does not work for me, either. I think my dyslexia made me see the adjacent output of `With` as the output of `Map`. When I looked again after your comment, it said `TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]`. I guess my mind switched it on me. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, increasing the WorkingPrecision seems to get around the bug!